# Close all files in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, editor

**Is there a way to close all files from notepad++ less painfull than going over every single one of them at the time.**

I always use it for quick editing files and now there are more 200 files open in the editor which is a bit annoying.
I have tried so far to close them by clicking on the close all button (in the menu toolbar) but still it's going over one single  of them at the time .
And I have also tried to close notepad++ program through task Manager but It still keep the files there.

> Here is the version of the notepad++ I'm using : Notepad++ v7.5.1
>   (64-bit)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Menu File > Close all

Comment: It's still ask : save file "167" ?

Comment: If you have files that have not been saved, it's going to ask if you want to save the file.

Comment: I don't need those files anymore so I just want to close them all

Comment: Well click don't save

Comment: That's where the pain reside

Comment: Close Notepad++ and delete the backup folder (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup).

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks ; You can post it post as the answer then I'll accept it

Comment: `Settings > Preferences > Backup` > Uncheck `Remember the current session for next launch`

Comment: C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup

Just rename this backup folder while notepad++ is not running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Via @Florent B.

> Click `Menu File`. Click `Close all`.

**Other Options:**
Right-click on a tab then you have four options.

```
Close <- close current tab.
Close all but this.
Close all to the left.
Close all to the right.
```

Your best bet is `Close all but this`. That will leave you at two total clicks to close all files.

Answer (score 6):

So Shortcut to Close All Tabs is ctrl + shift + W

And in Case you have lot many tabs unsaved and you don't want to save those and close forcefully

then 
ctrl + shift + W
then press shift + N continuous till all tabs get closed :)

Answer (score 3):

I never wanted the previously opened files to be popped up again when I open notepad. I was going through options and found out a way for the files not to pop up whenever you open notepad.
for that

1. Run Notepad++ as an administrator.
2. select the settings option on the top of notepad++
3. Select "preferences". and then select the option "backup"
4. In that uncheck the "Remember current session for next launch" option
5. Then on you wont see your previously opened files pop up

Hope it helps, Sorry for any grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings -> Shortcut Mapper - > Close All.
And then, set your own shortcut to close all the documents in Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++ v7.5.6 you should be able to 
    Ctrl+Shift+W